# While opting out of AWS SNS text message (using STOP), I am getting reply, "service is not available on this smartcode" text message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Whenever I am trying to unsubscribe my phone number from the topic by sending "STOP" via text message, it is reverting me with a text message stating "service is not available on this smartcode" from the same short code id. Tried this with multiple numbers. I chose the Asia Pacific(Mumbai) region. Any help would be appreciated.

[Click here to see the ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfKKD.jpg)

Comment: do you own the short code via AWS?  is the short code for the same country that you are sending the text message to?

Comment: No. I don't own the short code.

Comment: @JDD Attached the screenshot.

Comment: @sanista any update on this ??